# Python unittest; assertTrue() strange behavior

Tags: python, python-3.7, python-unittest

I was amazed to see something like this in a code review request today:

```
import unittest
class SomeTestClass(unittest.TestCase):
@classmethod
def setUpClass(cls):
  ...
  cls.assertTrue(some_condition, "a message")
```

This sparked my interest as I know in `python2.7` you could not call `assertXXX` methods in a `classmethod` or a `staticmethod` and it would have failed there. I quickly put up some test code to check:

```
import unittest
class TestClass(unittest.TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
      var = 34
      cls.assertTrue(var == 34)
      cls.assertTrue(var == 33)

    def test_123(self):
      self.assertFalse(False)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   unittest.main()
```

Hoping for python language to fail on calling `assertTrue` which is an instance method in a static context and if it works (I thought may be in `python3` it changed) then `cls.assertTrue(var == 33)` to raise an `AssertionError`. But to much of my surprize None of the above happened and I see:

```
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s
OK
```

I am using `python3.7`. My questions are:

1. shouldn't this fail as `assertTrue` is an instance method? note that `assertFalse` and other  such method do cause a failure
2. If it does work shouldn't `assertTrue` fail when the condition evaluate to `False` ?

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with how functions are bound in 3.x. Consider a simpler example:

```
class Example:
    def method(self):
        print(f'Example.method called on {self!r}')

Example.method('a string')
```

Comment: Karl Knechtel
Good point, but then why would `assertFalse()` not behave the same way ?

Comment: It would, I'm pretty sure, if you called it the same way. Your code doesn't.

Comment: hey sorry I did not put `cls.assertFalse(var == 34)` in the code, that does not behave how `assertTrue` does. Please give it a try. The `assertFalse` in my code example above was to show that it works in the context of instance method.